# Provisioing profiles not working in migrated mac

Tags: ios, xcode, ssl, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile

I have an app that I have given for submission that was rejected due to some privacy issue. I have corrected the problem and am trying to submit it from a new mac. I have two provision profiles which I made earlier. 'P release' and 'P ad-hoc'. As the name implies 'p release' was for app store and 'p ad-hoc' was for testflight insider testing.

Both were working perfectly on the earlier machine. When I had to move, I exported the developer profile from the mac machine by going to xcode-preferences-accounts.
Also i made a back up of code.

Now on the new machine, I used the backup and imported the developer profile. Now I made some changes and wanted to try on the testflight, therefore i selected 'p ad-hoc' as provisioning profile in build setting in project target and started the archive process. There was a prompt to use private key from local keychain, I selected 'allow'. Next when i clicked on 'upload to app store' the provisioning profile change to 'p release'.

If i delete 'p-release' from the machine then while uploading to app store it says no matching profile found.

I tried deleting the old provisioning profile from apple developer center and created new provisioning profiles but the same problem. 
Then i also tried to request a certificate from keychain and uploaded it to in the apple developer center and generated new certificates for push. 
But then i started receiving that the error 'no codesigning identity found'

So now I think i will simply redo the whole process by deleting all certificates from apple developer center.

So can anyone tell me what could have gone wrong?

Also **another very important question** that arises from the above : Lets say my application goes live, and i have obtained a .p12 certificate and used it for push notifications. Now if in future I redo the whole process, and lets say I delete every certificate (apn production, apn development and ios distribution, ios development) and then generate new p12 certificates. And then I discard the old p12 and use this new p12 certificate, will the push notifications work in old installations of my applications that were submitted using the older certificates?

Comment: Sounds like you forgot to backup and restore the certificates. Provisioning profiles are tied to a specific certificate.

Comment: @rmaddy Which certificate? .cer files? or certsignrequest file? also can you answer the second question

Comment: The certificate used to create the provisioning profiles.